# shell script on server falis when run from web page

Tags: php, html, bash

If I ssh to server and cd public_html and run the shell script (below) it works fine.

**One second thought, it would be easier to just setup a crontab on the server and have it run every day.**

But if I run it from the web page outlined below, the zip file 'chessclub.zip' is not created or synced. The bash script is located on the server at 'home/user/public_html/ but it won't be found and executed. **How can I get the bash script to execute on the server, not locally?**

**HTML**

```
<button onclick = 'getZIP.php;'>ZIP IT</button>
```

PHP 'getZIP.php'

```
<?php 
shell_exec("/home/user/public_html/backup_cccr");
?>
```

SHELL SCRIPT ON SERVER ("backup_cccr")

```
#!/bin/bash
zip -r -9 -FS chessclub.zip * -x chessclub.zip
```

Comment: You probably need to specify absolute paths for the source and zip files. Just because the script is in /home/user/public_html does not mean that'll be its working directory as it runs.

Comment: I edited backup_cccr on the server: zip -r -9 -FS /home/{user}/public_html/chessclub.zip * -x /home/{user}/public_html/chessclub.zip and  locally as <?php shell_exec("/home/{user}/public_html/backup_cccr"); ?> and it didn't work. It executes manually on the server, but not when invoked from a local php script.

Comment: What happens if you ssh to the server and run it *without* `cd`ing into its directory?

Comment: I tried creating the zip from within the public_html and from outside. Ended up having chessclub.zip re-added each time and increasing zip filesize by 15 mb each time.

Answer (score 0):

Best idea was to scrap the php zip functions for bash zip functions because bash function are better: (backup_cccr)

```
#!/bin/bash
zip -r -9 -FS chessclub.zip public_html/* -x 'public_html/chessclub.zip'
cp chessclub.zip public_html/
```

Copying the updated chessclub.zip to public_html means the file is accessible from a web browser

I used a daily cron job to automatically create a backup. Easy to do.